# mbpoll writing data to relay board

Tags: modbus

I am having trouble writing the correct data to a relay board using mbpoll.
It uses Modbus RTU, and the data that I NEED to write is: `01 06 00 01 01 00 D9 9A`

The command I am using is: `sudo ./mbpoll -m rtu -b 9600 -0 -t 4:hex -P none -v  /dev/ttyUSB0 -1 0001`
This gives me a result of:

```
Protocol configuration: Modbus RTU
Slave configuration...: address = [1]
                        start reference = 1, count = 1
Communication.........: /dev/ttyUSB0,       9600-8N1 
                        t/o 1.00 s, poll rate 1000 ms
Data type.............: 16-bit register, output (holding) register table

[01][06][00][01][00][01][19][CA]
Waiting for a confirmation...
<01><06><00><01><00><01><19><CA>
Written 1 references.
```

It is slightly off and the relay board does not respond. Any idea how I can use mbpoll to write the correct formatted data?

Thank you very much!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to request register 256 (PDU addressing as you have specified `-0`). So the following (using different port) should work:

```
mbpoll -m rtu -b 9600 -0 -t 4:hex -P none -v  /dev/ttymxc0 -1 256
```

Results in:

```
Protocol configuration: Modbus RTU
Slave configuration...: address = [1]
                        start reference = 1, count = 1
Communication.........: /dev/ttymxc0,       9600-8N1
                        t/o 1.00 s, poll rate 1000 ms
Data type.............: 16-bit register, output (holding) register table

[01][06][00][01][01][00][D9][9A]
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, and just for future people, the command: mbpoll -m rtu -b 9600 -0 -t 4:hex -P none -v  /dev/ttymxc0 -1 512 turned the relay OFF